# Why am I getting 170 Xp instead of 530+ at the Anachronia Agility Course?

Tags: runescape

I am currently playing RS3 and I was trying to level up Agility. I was watching some videos of the new agility course at Anachronia and while watching videos I saw that the players would get 530+ exp for completing a lvl 30 obstacle group. I am doing everything right but I am only getting 170 exp for completing the lvl 30 obstacle. Is that normal? If not, how can i fix it?

P.S. My agility lvl is 41

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that can influence your experience gains.

- The [Nimble Outfit](https://runescape.wiki/w/Nimble_outfit) can increase your experience gain per 1% per piece (6% maximum)
- [Silverhawk boots](https://runescape.wiki/w/Silverhawk_boots) can also be used to gain extra leveled experience
- An XP boosting event may be taking place, thus increasing experience gains
- [Bonus Experience](https://runescape.wiki/w/Bonus_experience) may be consumed to increase actual experience gains

According to the official wiki page regarding [Anachronia's Agility Course](https://runescape.wiki/w/Anachronia_Agility_Course), level 30 course only grants a maximum of 310 xp, thus it's quite likely that the difference experienced may have come from the aforementioned factors